# How to Control Buttons via Numpad Keys in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

I have this requirement that the users need to use the keyboard numpad keys to control specific button assigned to it and perform each function.

Example:

if Numpad key 0 is press then Button0 will be triggered.

Or

```
if(Numpad0 is pressed)
{
 //do stuff
  if (inputStatus)
        {
            txtInput.Text += btn0.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            txtInput.Text = btn0.Text;
            inputStatus = true;
        }
}
else if(Numpad1 is pressed)
{
//do stuff
}
```

In my form i have a split container then all Buttons are located on a group box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using ProcessCmdkey Solves the Problem:

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {       
           if (keyData == Keys.Numpad0)
                {
                    Numpad0.PerformClick();
                    return true;
                }

            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set `KeyPreview` to `true` and handle `KeyDown`:

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyDownEventArgs e) {
    if(e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9)
        ((Button) this["Button" + (e.KeyCode - Keys.NumPad0).ToString()]).PerformClick();
}
```

I haven't tested it, but that's about how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a window handler for the keydown event:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys./*numpad keys*/)
    {
        // do something such as call the click handler for your button!
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Or you can do it for the Form instead! You didn't specify, but the logic is the same.

And don't forget to turn `KeyPreview` on. Use `Keys.NumPad0`, `Keys.NumPad1`, etc for the number pad keys. See MSDN for the [Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

If you want to prevent the keys default action being performed set `e.Handled = true` as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Form's `KeyPreview` to `true` and handle the `Form.KeyDown` event.

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
    {
        Button0.PerformClick()
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
    {...}
    ...
}
```